# What is free-ware (or just cheaper) analog to Tableau (ad-hoc BI)?

Tags: report, business-intelligence, adhoc

I need an ability to connect to different sources (minimum MS SQL and Excel) and EASILY create ad-hoq reports, on the fly. What is the solution for this, apart from Tableau (http://www.tableausoftware.com/)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could consider GoodData (www.gooddata.com) - a cloud business intelligence solution. It's not free but definitely cheaper than Tableau, especially if you want to enable multiple users to create ad hoc reports.

GoodData enables you to create remote *projects* (= cloud based data marts) and provides a convenient user interface to instantly create or edit ad hoc reports or to organize reports into dashboards.

You can use the GoodData command line tool to connect to existing data sources and load them into your GoodData project, see https://developer.gooddata.com/getting-started/ for details or let me know if you'd need any help to set up your project.

Quick disclaimer: I work at GoodData and I've written some parts of the CL tool mentioned above.

Pavel

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's an old question, but I've recently came across the wonderful tool called Microsoft PowerPivot. It is just the thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

for combining several types of datasources and creating reports from them, I use  BellaDati BI (www.belladati.com). They have a completely FREE personal version (with no functionality limits) after registration here http://www.trgiman.eu/en/belladati/product/personal or you can log in with Google account directly on https:/service.belladati.com

- it handles XLS, CSV, XML, databases
- supports joins of data sets
- crates tables, pivot tables and charts with interactive drill down
- exports of reports to csv, xls
  ...

It should be the suitable tool for you. The paid tariffs of this product are for bigger teams and companies.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

[Web Pivot Table](http://webpivottable.com) is a great choice. It is web based and provides ad-hoc reporting functions to both CSV/Excel data files and OLAP cubes. You can use free edition for free and if you want to customize it and embed it into your web application, the price is far less than Tableau.

Here is [Demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) and [Documents](http://webpivottable.com/documents).